# Uniform convergence of a Mollifier Sequence $f_{\rho}:=g_{\rho}*f$

Tags: uniform-convergence, convolution, pointwise-convergence, regularization

If I have a function $g_{\rho} \in C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R^n})$ $($i.e **$C^{\infty}$ function compactly supported in $\mathbb{R^n}$$)$**.

Defined by: $g_{\rho}:=\frac{1}{\rho^n}g(\frac{x}{\rho})$, where $g \in C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R^n})$, and $\int_{\mathbb{R^n}}g(x)dx=1$.

And if I defined $f_{\rho}:=g_{\rho}*f$, where $f \in C(\Omega)$ $($or $C(\overline{\Omega}))$, $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R^n}$.

Then what can we say about the limit of $f_{\rho}$ as $\rho \rightarrow 0$? And in what sense?

My Dr. said: $f_{\rho} \rightarrow f$ as $\rho \rightarrow 0$ locally uniformly in $\Omega$. And then continued to say: this means the **pointwise convergence on all $\Omega$**

But how might this be true?

Comment: How does $g_\rho$ depend on $\rho$?

Comment: Ive edited my question

Comment: Have you tried to prove it?  If so, what did you try?  You can probably find a proof of this in first-year graduate level books on partial differential equations or harmonic analysis.

Comment: @PeterMorfe But how does locally uniform convergence imply pointwise cv?

Comment: @sara, locally uniform convergence implies pointwise convergence in any ball contained in $\Omega$, doesn't it?

Comment: @PeterMorfe I really dont know, and if this happens, so hove to move from the ball to entire $\Omega$?

Comment: @sara, do you know the definition of local uniform convergence?  It feels like we are getting ahead of ourselves here.

Comment: @PeterMorfe No I dont know, can you please explain it to me, and how this gave the p.w convergence please.